# Warning: passing incompatible type to setRootViewController:

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uideviceorientation

I am doing a calculator for the iPhone, where on rotation of the device, a new view is displayed, and I am getting the following three errors:

> CalculatorAppDelegate.m:21: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct CalculatorViewController *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'setRootViewController:' from distinct Objective-C type`

this error (and below) is from code:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

> CalculatorAppDelegate.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIViewController *' from 'CalculatorViewController *'

the below error is from:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];`
```

> CalculatorViewController.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation'

Comment: Looks like your `CalculatorViewController` is not a subclass of `UIViewController`. You should double-check your CalculatorViewController.h file.

Answer (score 3):

For your first 2 errors:

- Either `CalculatorViewController` is not declared as a subclass of `UIViewController` in your .h file
- Or the compiler doesn't know about it, because you forgot the `#import "CalculatorViewController.h"` in your code to let the compiler know about its definition

For your last issue, this is because you misuse `UIDeviceOrientation` and `UIInterfaceOrientation`, which are not the same type (even quite related).

- `UIInterfaceOrientation` define the orientation of the **user interface**. It only has 4 values: Portrait, Landscape Left, Landscape Right or UpsideDown.
- `UIDeviceOrientation` define the orientation of the **device**. It has 6 values, defining that your device is straight up, turns 90° left or right, upsidedown, or faceing down ou up.

---

If you setup your interface so that it does **not** rotate (`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` returns YES only for one of the 4 `UIInterfaceOrientation`), your `UIDeviceOrientation` can still change (nothing prevent the user to turn his/her iPhone into any position), but your `UIInterfaceOrientation` won't change.

If you setup your interface so this it **does rotate** (`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` always returns YES), when the user turns his/her iPhone to the right, **`UIDeviceOrientation` will be `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight`** because the iPhone will be turned right... and **`UIInterfaceOrientation` will be `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`**, because the interface orientation will be rotated 90° to the left, so that because the device is turned to the right, the interface will still be displayed horizontally to the user.

You can notice that `UIInterfaceOrientation` and `UIDeviceOrientation` have **opposed values** (for enums that are common to both; of course for `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown` there is no corresponding `UIInterfaceOrientation`)